# What is the object method in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I found a piece of action code in a helper, its purpose is to change the API content of render JSON in the controller:

```
class Users::RefDecorator < Draper::Decorator
    delegate_all

    def ava
      object.user.ava
    end
```

User is another model, and ava is its column. But what does the "object." at the beginning mean?

Comment: Based on the code that you gave, object is `nil`. Can you please provide the full class code in order to answer this?

Comment: See the readme for draper gem https://github.com/drapergem/draper#accessing-the-model. `object` references decorated model.

Comment: What is the ```strftime("%A, %B %e")``` means?

Comment: You can find it in the documentation https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This decorator inherits from `Draper::Decorator` and `object` is a method defined on [`Draper::Decorator`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/drapergem/draper/Draper/Decorator). Quote from the [docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/drapergem/draper/Draper%2FDecorator:object):

> `#object` ⇒ `Object` (readonly)
>
> Also known as: `model`
>
> Returns the object being decorated.

It returns the object that was passed to as the first argument to the [decorator's `initialize`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/drapergem/draper/Draper%2FDecorator:initialize).

Answer (score 2):

In case of `Draper::Decorator` as a parent class, `object` refers to the original object.

So I imagine that you wrote something like this:

```rb
user = SpecialUserClass.new

decorated_user = user.decorate
# or
decorated_user = Users::ReferrerProfileDecorator.decorate(user)

# now
decorated_user.object == user
```

Though by adding `delegate_all`  you don't see it that often. From the original gem documentation:

> methods have been made available on the decorator by the delegate_all call

Answer (score -1):

> What is the object method in Ruby

There is no method named `object` in Ruby.

> But what does the "object." at the beginning mean?

It is sending the message `object` to the implicit receiver `self` (in some other languages, this would be called "calling the method `object` on `this`").

This method seems to be defined by some library you are using. However, it is not one of the libraries that you tagged your question with, so it is hard to tell where it might come from.